# Cannot assign variables when doing JSON in android studio

Tags: android, json

I want to execute taking data from JSON as shown below. But when 
Toast.makeText(this, MangIDtrailer.size () + "..... check size of Array IDtrailer .....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
it returns 0.

I don't know what the cause is.

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView Listmovie;
ArrayList<String> MangIDtrailer;
public static ArrayList<InfoMovie> inforMovieArrayList;
AdapterMovie adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    String url1 ="http://the....ying";
    inforMovieArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MangIDtrailer = new ArrayList<>();
    MangIDtrailer = GetIDMovie(url1);
    inforMovieArrayList = DataMovie(MangIDtrailer);
    Listmovie = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListMovie);
    adapter = new AdapterMovie(this, R.layout.movielist, inforMovieArrayList);
    Listmovie.setAdapter(adapter);
    Listmovie.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this,Review_Movie.class);
            intent.putExtra("IDmovie",i);
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, ""+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

public ArrayList<String> GetIDMovie (String Url) {
    final ArrayList<String> ArrayID = new ArrayList<>();
    final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, Url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String IDTrailer;
                JSONArray jsonArrayFreeMovies = response.getJSONArray("FreeMovies");
                for (int i=0; i < jsonArrayFreeMovies.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectFreeMovies = jsonArrayFreeMovies.getJSONObject(i);
                    IDTrailer = jsonObjectFreeMovies.getString("trailer_id");
                    ArrayID.add(IDTrailer);
                    Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, i+"************", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, MangIDtrailer.get(2)+"check Data ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    queue.cancelAll(jsonObjectRequest);
    return ArrayID;
}

public ArrayList <InfoMovie> DataMovie (ArrayList<String> MangIDtrailer) {
    final ArrayList<InfoMovie> inforMovieArray = new ArrayList<>();
    final String linkDetail = "http://tk/api/trailers/movDetail?trailer_id=";
    final RequestQueue queue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
```

//////////////Check that MangIDtrailer.size () has no data////////////////////////////////////
        Toast.makeText(this, MangIDtrailer.size()+".....check size of Array IDtrailer .....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
    for (int i=0; i<MangIDtrailer.size(); i++) {
        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest2 = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, linkDetail + MangIDtrailer.get(i) + "&test_fullVer=1", null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        try {
                            String linkposter, linkbackdrop, namemovie, overviewmovie, Release_date, Urltrailer;
                            Float Vote_average;
                            String linkHot = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/";
                            JSONObject jsonObjectInfo = null, jsonObjectMore = null;
                            JSONObject jsonopFreeMovies1 = response.getJSONObject("FreeMovies");
                            if (jsonopFreeMovies1.has("FreeMovies")) {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cos ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                JSONObject jsonObjectFreeMovies2 = jsonopFreeMovies1.getJSONObject("FreeMovies");
                                jsonObjectInfo = jsonObjectFreeMovies2.getJSONObject("Info");
                                jsonObjectMore = jsonObjectFreeMovies2.getJSONObject("More");
                            } else {
                                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Khoong cos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                jsonObjectInfo = jsonopFreeMovies1.getJSONObject("Info");
                                jsonObjectMore = jsonopFreeMovies1.getJSONObject("More");
                            }
                            namemovie = jsonObjectInfo.getString("title");
                            Urltrailer = jsonObjectInfo.getString("trailer_urls");
                            linkposter = linkHot + jsonObjectInfo.getString("thumbnail");
                            overviewmovie = jsonObjectMore.getString("overview");
                            linkbackdrop = linkHot + jsonObjectMore.getString("backdrop_path");
                            Release_date = jsonObjectMore.getString("release_date");
                            Vote_average = Float.valueOf(jsonObjectMore.getLong("vote_average"));
                            inforMovieArray.add(new InfoMovie(namemovie, overviewmovie, linkposter, linkbackdrop, Vote_average, Release_date));
                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this,namemovie + "-" + overviewmovie + "-" + Vote_average, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Lỗi", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Main2Activity.this, "Lỗi Try catch", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        queue2.add(jsonObjectRequest2);

    }
    return inforMovieArray;
}
```

}

Comment: Actually network operation is asynchronous, so you have to wait till operation has been completed to get data. You check data size before getting data from server

Comment: @Md Asaduzzaman 
I checked, the data has been returned in the GetIDMovie function, but when passed through the DataMovie function, it is equal to null.

Do you have a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As you suggested
`Toast.makeText(this, MangIDtrailer.size()+".....check size of Array IDtrailer .....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();` 
This is where you are getting size zero, which is absolutely true, because you have only initialized your array `MangIDtrailer` and it is an empty array. Your function `GetIDMovie(url1);` has a loop which populates your `MangIDtrailer` array which is below where you have called the toast. So your array is empty and thus its size returns `zero`. 
One handy tip for you, you should name your functions in camelCase with first letter of your word in lowercase. `GetIDMovie(url1)` seems more like a class constructor. :)

**EDIT:**
The above solves your initial problem.

To fully solve your problem, you have to understand that Network Operations are asynchronous, meaning they will execute after sometime or they may return no value at all depending on various conditions, like network bandwidth, your server state, the parameters passed to your HTTP requests, etc.

You have two network calls in your above code; in functions: `GetIDMovie()` and `DataMovie()`. The second function requires an array of `ID`s which is only available if your first request is complete and returns an array of ids. So what you would want to do is, only after you get the array of ids ie. in `onResponse` of `GetIDMovie()` after the for loop, you should make a call to `DataMovie()`.

This however is really ugly solution. I hope you will research further for better solution.

Comment: Thank you! I will note the name my functions in camelCase.

Can you show me how to fix the problem MangIDtrailer.size () returns zero? I do not know how to handle it to execute the function DataMovie

Comment: Your `MangIdtrailer` should be alright after execution (ie. after loop). Its just that you have called `Toast.makeText(this, MangIDtrailer.size()+".....check size of Array IDtrailer .....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`  where the array has no data.

Comment: Remove line `Toast.makeText(this, MangIDtrailer.size()+".....check size of Array IDtrailer .....",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: I tried running but the for loop in DataMovie Function is not executed.
It seems MangIDtrailer is not receiving data